# Include a js file to another js file written within document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

i have a file called as sub.js

```
$(document).ready(() => console.log("sub"))
```

also i have a main.js file

```
$(document).ready(() => {
   console.log("main file")
})
```

using es6 import can i require the sub.js file to main.js file

expected output (like in the react, i hope this is the wrong expected output, but just want to know whether there is a solution)

sub.js

```
$(document).ready(() => console.log("sub"))
export default sub
```

main.js file

```
import sub from './sub'
$(document).ready(() => {
   console.log("main file")
})
```

Comment: you need to use export/import statements, but before that the use case of this is important,

Comment: i have included the babel.

Comment: in main.js file the code expected is

import Sub from './sub.js

Comment: @brk `browser does not support export/import`.. chrome, edge, opera, safari do, and firefox (using a config flag) does - so ... ***internet explorer** does not support export/import* would be accurate - and, really kill it now :p

Answer (score 1):

Change sub.js:

```
export function sub() { console.log("sub") }
```

in main.js file do:

```
import { Sub } from './sub.js'

$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("main file")
    sub();
})
```

This is using a *named export*. You can also use a *default export* in `sub.js`:

```
export default function() { console.log("sub") }
```

and then

```
import Sub from './sub.js'

$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("main file")
    sub();
})
```

Comment: how i can ensure that the sub.js is loaded after the dom gets loaded. Since the sub.js code is written without document..ready

Comment: You remove the document.ready part of it and just do the console.log part in sub.js. You call the imported function inside your main.js file's document.ready section then.

Comment: i hope if you write the import statement in the main.js document.ready it wont work. the import statements should be called before the code. Else you need to use lazy loading method.

Comment: You cannot import *inside* functions. Aside from that I don't understand your last comment. Try to be clearer even if English is not your main language.

Comment: yes. let me try your solution. I didn't seen your updated solution

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {, i  am  getting the error when using import {Sub}. I checked my google chrome version its 65. also i am using babel.

Comment: Then obviously your Babel is not configured in a way that it would do what you need it to do. Impossible to answer from afar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166507/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-connexo).