# Can I call a function from a file JavaScript from another file1.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched through StackOverflow and  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871684/call-a-function-func1of-file1-js-from-func2-of-file2-js-file-and-func1-uses-a-gl), but I can't seem to make it work in my JQuery project. Premise: When the function were all in one file the code just worked fine.
I have to files: file1.js

```
export{hextorgb, randomColor, rgbtohex};

$(document).ready(function () {

    function hextorgb(hex) {
        var rgb = /^#{1}([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})/i.exec(hex);
        rgb[1] = parseInt(rgb[1], 16).toString(10);
        rgb[2] = parseInt(rgb[2], 16).toString(10);
        rgb[3] = parseInt(rgb[3], 16).toString(10);
        return rgb;
    }

    function randomColor() {
        var color = "#";
        while (color.length < 7) {
            color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
        }
        return color;
    }

    function rgbtohex(color) {
        var hex = parseInt(color).toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }

})
```

and this file2.js

```
import {hextorgb,randomColor, rgbtohex} from "./file1.js";

$(document).ready(function () {
    
function generateRandomCol() {
       var rgb = randomColor();
        var rgbarray = hextorgb(rgb);
        output(rgbarray[1], rgbarray[2], rgbarray[3]); /*where output is another function defined in this file */
        $("#redslider").val(rgbarray[1]);
        $("#redoutput").val(rgbarray[1]);
        $("#greenslider").val(rgbarray[2]);
        $("#greenoutput").val(rgbarray[2]);
        $("#blueslider").val(rgbarray[3]);
        $("#blueoutput").val(rgbarray[3]);
    }

    $("#generaterandom").click(function () {
        generateRandomCol();

    })

    $("body").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            generateRandomCol();
        }
    })


})
```

and I put those in the head of my HTML file:

```
<head> 
<script src="../js/file1.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="../js/file2.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
```

I would like to use the functions in file1.js into file2.js (because I'll use them in other Javascript (JQuery) files. It should be fine with the *export* and *import* as far as I've read, but it doesn't work. The *import* in file2.js totally breaks my code, even the parts that work without the file1.js functions, so I think I might be doing something wrong there?

I really can't figure it out. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The first block has functions inside a ready handler (another function) as such, those functions are only available in that function. Just take those functions outside the ready handler.

Comment: First, thank you very much. 
I deleted the "$(document).ready(function () { })" from the first block (file1.js), but the code still isn't working. It's like i'm doing something wrong with the import as the whole file2.js won't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include a js file to another js file written within document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186513/include-a-js-file-to-another-js-file-written-within-document-ready)

Comment: You're referring to file.js and file2.js in your question, but you are also referring to `"../js/function.js"` and `"../js/slider.js"`. Please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: I think you switch the export and the import line. The functions you want to use in a other file should be export and then import where you want to use the files

Comment: Thank you so much to every single one of you! I finally fixed it. 
I'll post an answer with my solution (it was something really dumb, as me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, thank you everyone.
There were some errors.

1. the one [Lee Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933198/lee-taylor) kindly pointed out. There shouldn't have been $(document).ready(function () {}) in file1.js because it's a function and every function inside that can't be exported because they exist within the ready function.
2. the missing "type=module" from the  tag. from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619778/how-to-use-es6-modules-while-creating-jquery-plugin)

> The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module".

3. one function that was in file1.js was trying to call a function in file2.js, but I didn't import/export any function from file2.js.

Unfortunatly I updated my code gradually while I was trying to find the solution, so the code you see now it's working, but if someone has the same problem just try check these things!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).